# Android App authentication to Node.js web application using passport with local strategy

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, passport.js

I have a web application running on node.js which uses a passport.js middleware for authentication.

I have been trying to create an android application to use with my web app. I have created a separate endpoint for the mobile authentication.

the following is my route code:

```
router.post('/mobileauth', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
successRedirect: '/successmobile',
failureRedirect: '/failmobile',
failureFlash: true,
}));

router.get('/successmobile', function(req, res, next){
res.send('success!');
});

router.get('/failmobile', function(req, res, next){
res.send('fail!');
});
```

If I run this endpoint from the web, it will work just fine, but otherwise, running this on my android app always results to the failureRedirect.

Here is my activity code for my app.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText eAdd = findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
    EditText pw = findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button logIn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView res = findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    final String emailAdd = eAdd.getText().toString();
    final String pass = pw.getText().toString();

    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String url = "http://192.168.0.32:3000/mobileauth";
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            res.setText(response);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    res.setText("error");
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", emailAdd);
                    params.put("password", pass);

                    return params;
                }
            };

            queue.add(stringRequest);

        }
    });



}
```

These codes are just the initial codes as I am still a novice on both nodes and android development. I have been trying for days but I couldn't seem to make this work.

Hope you can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Is your Express app only an API or will your Express app also allow regular user login via a web form?

Comment: @Franciso Mateo, it also has a web form endpoint.